# Why in the Journal Transaction screen is the Post Period value being ignored by the REST API?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying  to use the REST API to create a record in the Journal Transactions screen.  The problem I'm running into is that if the Transaction Date I'm using is before the Post Period, I don't want the Post Period to default to the period of the Transaction Date.   In the UI, I can force the Post Period to be after the period of the Transaction Date, but it seems in the REST API, it ignores me setting the Post Period and defaults to the Period of the Transaction Date - and if that period is closed, it gives me an error.

Is this a bug that is known, or am I doing something wrong?

Here's a snippet of my JSON string - not sure that this matters, just wanted to show I was actually setting the Post Period field AFTER setting the transaction date....

```
{
"Module": {
    "value": "GL"
},
"TransactionDate": {
    "value": "10/31/2022 11:00:00 PM"
},
"PostPeriod": {
    "value": "012023"
},
"Ledger": {
    "value": "ACTUAL"
},
"Description": {
    "value": "ID: 7731"
},
"ControlTotal": {
    "value": "5842.32"
}
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Most likely the assignment of the values is happening in the order that the fields are defined in the DAC and I assume the Post Period is defined prior to the Transaction Date in the DAC

Comment: Samvel - Looked at that - doesn't seem to matter.  I've tried various orders.  Apparently this may be a bug as Acumatica has sent this to engineering for review...

Comment: @pmfith Did you manage to solve this? I have a similar problem.

Comment: From what I was told, it's a bug in their system.  They haven't reached out to us on whether it'll be fixed in a future build / version...